# How to get a const char* function to work?

Tags: c++, c, function, char, constants

So I have this `char const* blahblahblah(const char* s)` function but when I try to use `strcat(s, " ")` or `return s[k]`in it it says

```
const char*s
Error: argument of type "const char*" is incompatible of parameter of type "char"
```

If I want the function to stay as is what should I change in my parameters in order for it to work?

Comment: Alternatively, you could change nothing in  your function's prototype and internally, `strdup (...)` the `const char *` to satisfy this conversion safely. Of course you will have to remember to free it afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declare const char* s, then you should not write strcat(s, " "), because strcat modifies s.

if you declare char const* reverseWordsOnly, then why do you return s[k]? s[k] is not a pointer.

EDIT:
This depends on what you want to do. I don't know what you want to do in this function.

If you don't modify s, then declaring const char* s is OK.

If you want to return char const *, then maybe you want to return &s[k] instead of s[k].

Maybe you want to return char *, then you can cast &s[k] using (char *)&s[k].

Comment: Thanks but how do I get rid of the rubbish and weird things in my char if I do not add " "? And what should I return instead? (I'm not to familiar with pointers)

Answer (score 2):

It's because the `const` on the left-hand-side of the `*` means that what's *pointed* to is immutable:  `strcat` obviously needs to alter its parameter.  And `s[k]` will refer to a `char`, not any sort of `char *`.