# How to return a const char* in a function?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, constants

I'm giving you guys my whole code. It's a bit long so I most sincerely hope you get it:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char const* reverseWordsOnly(const char* s)
{
    int k;
    int p = strlen(s);


    for (int i = 0; i <= p; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == ' ')
        {

            for (k = i - 1; (k != -1) && (s[k] != ' ') && (s[k] != ',') && (s[k] != ';') && (s[k] != '.'); k--)
                return &s[k];
            return " ";

        }
        if (s[i] == ',')
        {

            for (k = i - 1; (k != -1) && (s[k] != ' ') && (s[k] != ',') && (s[k] != ';') && (s[k] != '.'); k--)
                return &s[k];
            return ",";

        }
        if (s[i] == ';')
        {

            for (k = i - 1; (k != -1) && (s[k] != ' ') && (s[k] != ',') && (s[k] != ';') && (s[k] != '.'); k--)
                return &s[k];
            return ";";

        }
        if (s[i] == '.')
        {

            for (k = i - 1; (k != -1) && (s[k] != ' ') && (s[k] != ',') && (s[k] != ';') && (s[k] != '.'); k--)
                return &s[k];
            return ".";

        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char s[1002];
    cin.getline(s, 1002, '\n');
    strcat(s, " ");
    reverseWordsOnly(s);
    return 0;
}
```

So what does it do.. It reverses the order of the words' letters in a string. For example, if you write down `Something.. terribly wrong.`, it should return `gnihtemoS.. ylbirret gnorw.`The interval and the dot stand as delimiters. Problem is that I must use this very very precise function `char const* reverseWordsOnly(const char*)` and I have absolutely no idea how to make it work with those constants and pointers. The code I have written is fully compilable but returns nothing but a blank space in the console. What have I done wrong? Any ideas? How to return those pointer values in the function?

Comment: Do you actually output anything? I don't see anything in this code that should show anything in the console.

Comment: @typ1232 I  `return &s[k]` in the four if cases.. It may not be right.. I experimented as it wouldn't let me `return s[k]` while I'm having a pointer.

Comment: Wasn't this posted earlier today - thought it was answered...

Comment: @user3213110 Sure, you function returns something, but you need something like `cout` or `printf` to show your string in the console.

Comment: @chux something similar was posted earlier today. It was answered indeed but it didn't really help me to get my code straight. I made a new question as it's slightly different and to avoid confusion which, apparently, has already been caused.

Comment: From this code I think you do not fully understand what return does.

Comment: How were you _expecting_ the body of each loop being an instant `return` to work?

Comment: @typ1232 Thanks but where should I put that `cout`? I haven't worked with functions much but I've never really used that with a function.

Comment: Suggest not editing your post after receiving an answer - maybe append your final thoughts instead.  That previous post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21350160/how-to-get-a-const-char-function-to-work question and answer does not make sense with the final edit.

Comment: @drescherjm You're right there, I do not. But yesterday I made a `bool` function which concluded with `return true/false` and an `int` one which returned an integer. I've never used `cout` with a function.

Comment: @chux - Basically what I did was as following: After quite the struggle I managed to write a proper code for what I needed - reversing the letters of the string words. I did it in the `main` function though, and where you now see a `return s[k]` and `return " "` it was `cout << s[k]` and `cout << " "`. It was working just fine. However, my assignment was to make this in a very specific `const char*` function.. When I tried to rewrite it in a way suitable for the function I majorly failed. So my question is how can I properly rewrite it so that it can work as a function?

Comment: You can not put a loop around return and assume your function will continue executing collecting all of the results from each of the returns. It absolutely will not do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

char const* reverseWordsOnly(const char* s){
    static string work;
    work = s;
    string::size_type start_pos = 0, end_pos;

    while(string::npos != (start_pos = work.find_first_not_of(" .,;", start_pos))){
        if(string::npos == (end_pos = work.find_first_of(" .,;", start_pos+1)))
            end_pos = work.length();
        reverse(&work[start_pos], &work[end_pos]);
        start_pos = end_pos + 1;
    }

    return work.c_str();
}

int main(){
    cout << reverseWordsOnly("Something.. terribly wrong.") <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can I just ask why you changed `static string work(s)` to `static string work; work = s;` because it worked beforehand as well?

Comment: @user3213110 ; It does not function as a new string when you call this function with another string.

Answer (score 1):

Either I'm missing something, or this should help:
 1. you get a const char *, even though you want to change it. the const keyword means your not suppose to change the content of the variable, so I would get rid of it.
 2. It seems like your not actually changing the string, even though it's what your function should do (by the way you described it)
 3. Try the strtok function to separate your sentence into words.
 4. Don't return random strings in the middle of your function - write the words, reversed into a new buffer (allocated using the "new" keyword), and return the pointer to that buffer at the **end** of your function.

If this isn't enough let me know and I can reply with some code that should do the job.

Also... Your function returns char *, but in your main function you never assign its return value to a variable.

Comment: Thanks, you can check out my latest comment on the question. I think it describes the situation better. I tried changing all my returns to `cout` and returned 0 at the end of the function and it all got messed up. When I input `What the`, instead of `tahW eht`, it outputs `t the at the hat the What the  e he the  `. This pointer stuff is really new to me and I don't really get its logic and how it differs from "non-pointers" in its use so I didn't really get what you told me about writing the things in another buffer. By the way,as I said,sadly enough I MUST use const char* and nothing else.